# Excel macro Help - group by

Tags: excel

I have two columns in my excel:

```
TableName   Function
   100        abc
   100        def
   100        xyz
   100        ghy
   100        ajh
   101        ahd
   101        lkj
   101        gtr
   102        afg
   102        vbg
   102        arw
   102       fgtr
```

I need output as

```
TableName     Function
    100     abc,def,xyz,ghy,ajh,
    101     ahd,lkj,gtr,
    102     102,102,102,102,
```

Comment: A pivot + macro recorder would do a perfect job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this simpler code,

```
Sub joinStr()
Dim i As Long, str As String, k As Long
Columns("A:B").Sort key1:=Range("A2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
str = Cells(2, 2)
k = 2
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
        str = str & "," & Cells(i + 1, 2)
    Else
        Cells(k, 4) = Cells(i, 1)
        Cells(k, 5) = str
        k = k + 1
        str = Cells(i + 1, 2)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly fine as expected for my values/data.

Comment: @Atul Great. Please mark the answer as correct to make it resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with VBA solution then following might help.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim dic As Variant, arr As Variant, temp As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")  'change Sheet4 to your data sheet

    With ws
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row  'get last row with data in Column A
        Set rng = .Range("A2:B" & lastRow)              'set the range of data
        Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        arr = rng.Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            temp = arr(i, 1)
            If dic.Exists(temp) Then
                dic(arr(i, 1)) = dic(arr(i, 1)) & ", " & arr(i, 2)
            Else
                dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
            End If
        Next
        .Range("D1") = "Table Name"         'display headers
        .Range("E1") = "Function"
        .Range("D2").Resize(dic.count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.keys) 'display table names
        .Range("E2").Resize(dic.count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dic.items) 'display funtions
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Result will be like in the image below.

[image]

To add this code press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> from excel. This will open Microsoft Visual Basic Editor, then click `Insert` > `Module` and paste the above code. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute the code.

Comment: Hi Mrig, For the column B I have values like this shown below. Its not working with that. It says Run time error 13. Seems like some datatype error.       Sample Column B value is cast(nvl(concat(To_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sostmp, 'ddMMMyyyy'))),' ', substr(sostmp,11,20)) ,'0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000') as timestamp),